# state is not defined error in using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying out react for my first time but got stuck, want to do multiple binding.

```
class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      price
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={e => this.setState({price: e.target.value})} placeholder="main price"/>
        <input type="text" placeholder="custom price"/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What's wrong with my above code? price is not defined? I already declare

```
this.state = {
   price
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is, When you write:

```
this.state = { price }
```

It will be treated as:

```
this.state = { price : price }
```

And it is throwing the error because **value price is not defined**.

To solve this issue either define the price or assign the value to key price like this:

```
this.state = { price : '' };
```

Check this snippet:

```js
str = 'a';

obj = {str};

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: correct. I was also checking same. My answer is wrong here.